Is poverty in the present life due to past life's bad Karma?
I am not looking for a general answer (like, all problems in this life are due to bad Karma of the past). I want to know specifically about poverty. Is it written anywhere in our scriptures, that being poor is due to the person's bad Karma?
Some modern Gurus, say that a soul chooses a life of poverty so that by facing struggle, it can spiritually progress more. Though, in the first place, I do not understand why you have to be poor to advance spiritually. Why does a soul deliberately choose a life of hardship? Is this claim backed by scripture? Or just another example, where the modern Guru's own imagination is fed to the public as Gospel truth?
So, in a nutshell, what is the reason for poverty according to the Hindu scriptures?


29 People belonging to the different classes and orders of life who
are steadfastly devoted to the Laws proper to them enjoy the fruits of
their deeds after death; and then, with the residue of those fruits,
take birth again in a prosperous region, a high caste, and a
distinguished family, with a handsome body, long life, deep vedic
learning, and virtuous conduct, and with great wealth, happiness, and
intelligence. 30 Those who act to the contrary disperse in every
direction and perish. 31
Dharmasutras of Gautama 11.29-11.31

This shows that if we are wealthy in the present birth then that is due to some good Karmas of the past life. Hence, it implies that poverty in the current birth is due to past life's bad Karmas.
